# Simple Qt5 application outputs blank lines on terminal

Tags: linux, qt, qt5

I am seeing strange behavior on the terminal when running the following simple Qt5 application:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QPushButton pb;
  pb.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

When I run this program as follows, the output is:

```
ton@willow:~/development/gb86 $ install/bin/gb86 &> /dev/null

ton@willow:~/development/gb86 $
ton@willow:~/development/gb86 $
```

So, even redirecting all output to `/dev/null` still results in two enter keypresses being sent to the terminal it seems. Some observations:

- Running the application from a non-X11 terminal and setting the correct `$DISPLAY` does not show the extra blank lines.
- Other Qt5 applications that link to the same Qt5 libraries on the same system have the same behavior. Other non-Qt5 applications started from the terminal do not have this behavior.
- Window manager is i3, the terminal emulator does not matter, I have tried several different ones (st, Alacrity, Kitty), and all have the same behavior. Changing `$TERM` has no effect either.
- Changing PS1 to a single '$' character, for example, does not change the behavior.
- Changing shells (Zsh/Bash) does not change the behavior.

Qt version is 5.11.2. Anyone got any idea of what is going on here? Any hints on how to debug this? Can someone reproduce this?

Comment: For me, no blank lines running your app from the terminal (Qt5.10.1 on Linux Mint 18.2)

Comment: @Scab, thanks for the feedback! I'll probably try a version compiled from source next to see whether that solves the annoyance.

Comment: No blank lines either on Arch Linux with kwin/kde and Qt 5.11.2 and konsole as terminal

Comment: Of course it leads to Qt source code examination. From practical point of view I don't want to waste the time for this. Not even for 50 more points. :-]

Comment: No blank lines using Qt 5.12 from Neon 18.1

Comment: Run your application in a terminal that can display non-printable characters. It's probably emitting some formatting "escape" codes.